# How to install jupyterhub on docker?

Tags: docker, jupyterhub

i have successfully done this fews months ago, everthing was doing fine until yesterday when i run the jupytherhub container in docker and it turned out that the jupyterhub page i used to visit is asking for some tokens. i somehow decided to deleted the container and images and planned to install it again like what i have done before. however, i've been working on this for hours by asking chatGPT and still can't figure out. i'm pretty new to this field and don't know what to do :(

BTW i'm using a windows labtop

some of the difficulties i have encountered these days are:

1. not being able to reach the page or page not found. everytime i get the url then paste it to the browser, i can't reach the page.
2. not being able to to sign in. sometimes i get in to a webpage but it require me to sign in, but i don't have a username and password, all i have is a token but i can't find the page to sign in with my token.

sorry for not being able to to provided any code because the my trying process is a mess, if there's no sufficient infromation i will tried my best to explain.

Comment: Please ask a single question at a time. Show the exact commands you're using, specific error messages, and any other details that would help identify the problem.